# Can I apply filters to Fabric.js primitives?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Is it possible to apply the Image filters to primitives, paths, shapes and text? It's kind of weird to be able to do them on the more complicated images, but not be able to blue a rectangle. Any "cheat" to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the fabric.js code, you will see that the fabric.js filter feature is creating a new image from the original image (i.e. each pixel in the new image is calculated by manually applying the filter to pixels in the original image). Thus, the fabric.js filter feature only applies to images.

Remember that fabric.js provides a model on top of a canvas element. The current standard specs for a canvas 2D rendering context does not support the general concept of filters.

Comment: Kind of a followup. Is there any way to convert a primitive into an image?

Comment: You could create a temp canvas that is off screen. Draw the primitive on the temp canvas. Apply the filter to the temp canvas. Then use the temp canvas as an image to draw on the main canvas.

Comment: For example:
var elem = document.createElement("canvas");
elem.setAttribute("width", 100);
elem.setAttribute("height", 100);
var temp = new fabric.Canvas(elem); 
temp.add(new fabric.Triangle({ left: 0, top: 0, width: 100, height: 100, fill: "blue" }));
var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale();
filter.applyTo(temp);
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ left: 25, top: 25, width: 50, radius: 50, fill: "red" }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Image(elem, {left: 50, top: 50}));